# How to display a blog post based on it's ID with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

In my News component I have an array of posts:

```
const cardInfo = [
      {
        id: 1,
        date: "12/07/2020",
        title: "Machine Learning",
        author: "Alex M.",
        text: "text1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        date: "12/07/2020",
        title: "AI",
        author: "Alex E.",
        text: "text2"
      }
   ]
```

A renderCard function that renders the array:

```
renderCard = (card, index) => {
return (
  <Row id={index}>
    <Col sm="10">
      <Card key={index}>
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle tag="h5" className="mb-2 text-muted">
            {card.title}
          </CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">
            Written on {card.date} by {card.author}
          </CardSubtitle>
          <CardText className="mb-2 text-muted">
            <ReadMoreReact
              text={card.text}
              readMoreText="Read more."
              min={160}
              ideal={200}
            />
          </CardText>
          <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">
            Category: {card.category}
          </CardSubtitle>{" "}
          <Button>Read more.</Button>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </Col>
  </Row>
);
};
```

Return statement that displays the array of posts and also titles of recent posts sorted by date:

```
return (
  <div>
    <CareersHeader />
    <div className="news">
      <h1 className="news__title" id="news-title">
        Blog
      </h1>
      <div className="news__content">
        <div className="item1 news__posts">
          {cardInfo.map(this.renderCard)}
        </div>
        <div className="item2 news__recent_posts">
          <div>Recents Posts:</div>
          <div>
            {cardInfo
              .sort((a, b) => (a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1))
              .map((post, index) => (
                <button onClick={what to do} key={index}>
                  {post.title}
                </button>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Post titles in recent posts list are buttons. When you click on a button, it should open that particular blog post. I have added in App.js this route:

```
<Route exact path="/news/:id" component={BlogPostDetails} />
```

BlogPostDetails component

```
return (
  <div>
    <CareersHeader />
    <div className="news">
      <h1 className="news__title" id="news-title">
        Blog
      </h1>
      <div className="news__content">
        <div className="item1 news__posts">
          <p>Blog post</p>
          {cardInfo.map((card) => (
            <div key={card.id}>{renderCard}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

However, I don't know how to match the id from URL with the id of the post title clicked.
I have tried with useParams() hook, but I was getting errors that I couldn't resolve (invalid hook call). Also, I am wondering if I could just create a function that would be called on a button click, something like this:

```
const displayPost= (index) => {
  const url = "/news/" + index;
  window.open(url, "_top");
};
```

I'm sure there is quite simple way in React to do this, just that I'm still quite new and don't understand the lifecycle. Help appreciated.

Comment: You can try using `window.location.pathname` or go through this example(https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) and make sure that you haven't missed anything

Comment: What 'react-router-dom' version are you using so you were getting an error with `useParams` hook?

Comment: :) This is exactly what I have tried implementing. The problem was that I was getting error saying I can't use hooks in class components. So I spent some time trying to resolve it, but to no avail. Thanks anyway, will take a further look.

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic the version was 15.something. I have updated it to the latest version, but was still getting the same error. I do have router-dom twice in my node modules and I read that this could be the problem too.

Comment: Yes, you can't use `hooks` in your `class` components. Since you have the latest version of `react-router-dom`, can you log `console.log(this.props.match.params)` in your `< BlogPostDetails />`?

Answer (score 0):

Title part.

```
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
    .    
    .
    .
    function MyPage({ ...rest }){
    
    const history = useHistory()

    return(
    .
    .
    .
    {cardInfo
     .sort((a, b) => (a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1))
     .map((post, index) => (
      <button onClick={() => history.push(post.id)} key={index}>
          {post.title}
      </button>
      ))}
    .
    .
    .
    }
    .
    .
    .
)
```

BlogPostDetails component

```
import { useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom'

const DetailPage = ({
...rest
}){

const match = useRouteMatch()
const { id } = match.params

const [ cardInfo, setCardInfo ] = useState([])
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false)
const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)

useEffect(() =>{
   setLoading(true)
   //fetch your details from API and set Loading, Error
}, [ id ])

return ( 
     <div>
        <CareersHeader />
        <div className="news">
           <h1 className="news__title" id="news-title">
               Blog
           </h1>
        <div className="news__content">
        <div className="item1 news__posts">
          <p>Blog post</p>
          {!loading && cardInfo.map((card) => (
            <div key={card.id}>{renderCard}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

}
```

Comment: Oh I guess I've missed few minutes and now I know you're making your component as class component. This will not helpful

Comment: Try ComponentDidMount life cycle. `if(window){ const { location } = window //do something with it}`  will get you a url information